# How to connect two EC2 instance in aws in the same network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

For example if my EC2-1 machine have the ip of 192.162.10.2 and the EC2-2 machine have the ip of 192.168.10.150 let say,

How can I achive this, Thank you

I'm try to connect to EC2 instance in the same network, I'm new in the cloud services.

Comment: Are they your _actual_ IP addresses? An IP address starting with `192.168.x.x` belongs to a [Private network - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) while `192.162.10.2` refers to a **public IP address**. You would not typically assign public IP ranges to an AWS VPC since it could not route over the Internet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'connect'?  Are you trying to SSH, FTP, RDP, etc.?  Overall, the more details you provide in your question the easier it is to get an answer.

Comment: This is just an example I just want to launch two EC2 instances in the same network like 192.168.10.x and the other Ec2 machine is 192.168.10.x I just want they are in the same network

Answer (score 2):

Amazon EC2 instances in the same VPC can communicate with each other.

Just make sure that the **Security Groups** associated with the instances permit the communication.

For example, let's say one EC2 instance is running a web application and the other is running a database. You might then create **two security groups**:

- A security group on the web server (`Web-SG`) that permits inbound traffic on port 80 and 443, plus all Outbound traffic
- A security group on the database server (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound traffic from `Web-SG` on the database port, plus all Outbound traffic

That is, `DB-SG` can specifically refer to `Web-SG` in its rules. This way, any EC2 instance that is associated with `Web-SG` will be permitted to access `DB-SG`. This is better than hard-coding IP addresses in security group rules.